# How much data can you store in a Parse String row

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So I'm fairly new to coding in swift and Parse, and I'm thinking of making a reviewing app, where users can write reviews etc. If I store these in Parse against the Users ID, will there be any problems as potentially the reviews could be very long.

So my main question is, how many character can be stored as a String in Parse?

Thanks

Comment: There's no limit. You can use any amount of text in Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific limit, but each object has a limit (which I think is currently 128k).

It may be better to store the review as a PFFile and link it to the review (or to optionally do that if the review is very long).